# How to hide error notifications in linux bash aliases?

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I wrote an alias to show me 10 biggest files and 10 biggest directories, so I tried to hide "du cannot access" and "no such file or directory" errors, without success.

Below the alias that I wrote:

```
alias big="echo 'Big Files:';find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -h | sort -hr | head -10 2>/dev/null;echo 'Big Directories:';du -sh * | sort -hr | head -n10 2>/dev/null"
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try piping the stderr stream of your `du` command to `/dev/null`

```
du -sh * 2>/dev/null | sort -hr
```

Comment: One small bug here (also present in the original): A file named `-foo` will be treated as an argument to `du`. Substituting either `./*` or `-- *` will prevent that.

Comment: The other answer should be the correct answer. Here I answered what was asked, not what what was intended.

Comment: what is foo? This bug is both for du and find? Thank you

Comment: @user7203212, `-foo` in this case, was a potential filename. If you run `touch ./-foo`, you just created a file by that name, and `du -sh *` will try to run with the `*` replaced with, among other filenames, `-foo`. I wouldn't call it a "bug", as such -- it's working-as-designed-and-documented, just not as a naiive user may *intend*.

Answer (score 4):

First: Use a function instead. This kind of application is *entirely* the wrong use case for an alias. A function will let you write your logic over multiple lines; can have conditional logic at execution (for instance, you can look at whether your function is given arguments, and behave differently if they're present); and can be called with the same syntax (it's just `big` to invoke in either case).

Second: Redirect stderr for the whole thing, not just the last segment.

```
big() {
  { # <-- open a block we can redirect
    echo 'Big Files:'
    find . -type f -exec du -h -- '{}' + |
      sort -hr |
      head -10

    echo 'Big Directories:'
    du -sh -- */ |
      sort -hr |
      head -n10
  } 2>/dev/null # <-- close, and redirect, that block
}
```

You can also do the same thing while continuing to use an alias (though, again, you shouldn't):

```
alias big='{ echo "Big Files:";find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -h | sort -hr | head -10;echo "Big Directories:";du -sh * | sort -hr | head -n10; } 2>/dev/null'
```

Here, wrapping the entire code in `{ }` lets us perform a single redirection across the whole block without the expense of a subshell (as would be created by wrapping the code in `( )`.

---

Other notes:

- `find -exec ... {} +` is POSIX-specified, and has the same efficiency gains as `find ... -print0 | xargs -0` (in terms of spawning no more instances of the child process than necessary), and in fact is slightly *more* efficient, as it avoids the need for an external `xargs` process.
- Using `*/` in the "Big Directories" segment tells the glob to expand only to directory names. Using the `--` argument prior tells `du` to interpret all arguments given past that point as file or directory names, even if you have a name that starts with a `-`.
- For folks trying to test this answer on MacOS, note that it depends on GNU sort. I personally have `gsort` installed via macports (`port install coreutils`), so used `sort() { gsort "$@"; }` to wrap the sort command while testing.